# Supposed "syntax error" in my code,"missing ';' before '.'"

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to this level of coding and am really hitting my wall on this error:

```
[Line 65] error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
```

Obviously this would usually mean a syntax error in my code, but I can't find it flippin anywhere. Any assistance (or a second set of eyes to see my error would be appreciated).

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
class RacingCar {

public: 
            Wheel* wheels[4];

            RacingCar()
            { 
                wheels[0] = new Wheel;
                wheels[1] = new Wheel;
                wheels[2] = new Wheel;
                wheels[3] = new Wheel;
            }

            RacingCar( RacingCar& refOldCar)
            {
//              new Wheel(refOldCar.wheels[0]->pressure);
                wheels[0] = new Wheel;
                wheels[1] = new Wheel;
                wheels[2] = new Wheel;
                wheels[3] = new Wheel;

                int a = refOldCar.speedCopy();
                **RacingCar.setSpeed(10);**
                RacingCar.Brake(50);
                RacingCar.Print();
                RacingCar.speed = refOldCar.speed;
            }
```

Thanks a ton for any help

Comment: FYI, the line in question is highlighted by **... these aren't actually in my code ;)

Comment: `Wheel *wheels[4];` seems rather unnecessary. Why not just use `Wheel wheels[4];` or `Wheel *wheels;`? For the latter use you can initialize it like this `wheels = new Wheel[4]`;

Comment: @gunbuster363 - Nah, this is a snippet of a very large class. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
RacingCar.setSpeed(10);
```

should be:

```
setSpeed(10);
```

which is shorthand for:

```
this->setSpeed(10);
```

Comment: Oh snap. I can't believe I missed that. I guess it's not the syntax error I'm used to. Really, really appreciate the prompt answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
RacingCar.setSpeed(10);
```

there is no such syntax. Write:

```
RacingCar::setSpeed(10);
```

or

```
setSpeed(10);
```

or

```
this->setSpeed(10);
```

Note that they all *may* have different meaning, although will probably work the same in your context.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that I was trying to reference something from within it. It makes sense. Appreciate the quick answer

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Class and Constructor (same as Class) name - e.g. RacingCar instead of refOldCar, this or just directly accessing members.

Answer (score 0):

Since the speed is unlikely to be a class-level property (affecting *all* cars), you probably meant to write:

```
this->setSpeed (10); // or, for the less anal, just "setSpeed(10);" :-)
```

This more correctly makes it an attempt to set the object-level property. A class-level property would reference `RacingCar::SomethingOrOther` (double-colon rather than dot) which is why it's thinking you need to close off the current statement before that `.` character.